# A series of questions on the subspace generated in a Hilbert space.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space.

**Note.** Where it is not subject to definition with the overline we indicate the closure of the set.

> **Claim 1.** Prove that the set $$\overline{\text{sp}}(A):=\bigcap\left\{M\;|\; M\;\text{is closed subspace such that}\; M\supseteq A\right\}$$ is a closed subspace of $H$.

**proof.** Clearly $0\in \overline{\text{sp}}(A)$. Let $x,y\in \overline{\text{sp}}(A)$ and $\alpha.\beta\in \mathbb{R}$, then $x$ and $y$ are in all closed subspaces $M$ that contain $A$ and therefore $\alpha x+\beta y\in \overline{\text{sp}}(A)$. It remains to show that $\overline{\text{sp}}(A)$ is closed.

Let $\{x_n\}\subseteq \overline{\text{sp}}(A)$ a sequence such that $x_n\to x$. Since $\{x_n\}$ is, in particular, a sequence in every closed subspace $M$ that contains $A$, results that $x$ is in every closed subspace $M$ that contain $A$ and so $x\in \overline{\text{sp}}(A)$.

> **Claim 2.** Let $A\subseteq H$ be a set we denote with $\text{sp}(A)$ the subspace generated by $A$: $$\text{sp}(A)=\left\{\sum_{k=1}^nc_kx_k\;|\; n\ge 1, c_k\in\mathbb{R}, x_k\in A\right\}.$$ I must prove that $$\overline{\text{sp}}(A)=\overline{\text{sp}(A)}$$

**proof.** Since $\overline{\text{sp}(A)}$ is a closed subspace that contains $A$, from definition of $\overline{\text{sp}}(A)$ we deduce that $\overline{\text{sp}}(A)\subseteq\overline{\text{sp}(A)}$. Let now $M$ a closed subspace such that $M\supseteq A$, since $M$ is closed with respect sum and product result that $\text{sp}(A)\subseteq M$, therefore $$\text{sp}(A)\subseteq M,\quad\text{for all closed subspace}; M\supseteq A,$$ from which it is deduced that $\text{sp}(A)\subseteq \overline{\text{sp}}(A)$, so using the claim $1$ we have that $\overline{\text{sp}(A)}\subseteq \overline{\text{sp}}(A)$.

> **Claim 3.** Let $L$ a subspace of $H$, we prove that $$\overline{L}=\overline{\text{sp}}(L)$$

**proof.** Since $\overline{L}$ is a closed subspace that contains $L$, from definition we have that $\overline{\text{sp}}(L)\subseteq \overline{L}$. On the other hand, $L\subseteq \text{sp}(L)$ and therefore using the claim $2$ we have $\overline{L}\subseteq \overline{\text{sp}(L)}=\overline{\text{sp}}(L)$.

> **Question.**
> Are the proposed proofs correct?

Comment: Yes they are. Shorter proof for Claim 1: any intersection of subspaces is a subspace and any intersection of closed subsets is closed.